# Recommendations to test API request layer in iOS apps using NSOperations and Coredata

Tags: ios, testing, rest, core-data, nsoperation

I develop an iOS app that uses a REST API. The iOS app requests data in worker threads and stores the parsed results in core data. All views use core data to visualize the information. The REST API changes rapidly and I have no real control over the interface.

I am looking for advice how perform integration tests for the app as easy as possible. Should I test against the API or against Mock data? But how to mock GET requests properly if you can create resources with POST or modify them with PUT?

What frameworks do you use for these kind of problems? I played with [Frank](http://www.testingwithfrank.com/), which looks nice but is complicated due to rapid UI changes in the iOS app. How would you test the "API request layer" in the app? Worker threads are NSOperations in a queue - everything is build asynchronously. Any recommendations?

Comment: Did you check out Graham Lee's recently published book "Test-Driven iOS Development"? Chapter 8 and 11 deal with concurrency, and the book covers aspect's of testing async consumption of Service APIs. I know that by the the time your post, the book wasn't available yet, that's why I mention it.

Comment: @cardinal Thanks for the hint. I will look it up!

Comment: For iOS integration tests, go with [KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF) all the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly advise you to mock the server.  Servers go down, the behavior changes, and if a test *failure* implies "maybe my code still works", you have a problem on your hands, because your test doesn't tell you whether or not the code is broken, which is *the whole point*.

As for how to mock the server, for a unit test that does this:

```
first_results = list_things()
delete_first_thing()
results_after_delete = list_thing()
```

I have a mock data structure that looks like this:

```
{ list_things_request : [first_results, results_after_delete], 
  delete_thing_request: [delete_thing_response] }
```

It's keyed on your request, and the value is an array of responses for that request in the order that they were seen.  Thus you can support repeatedly running the same request (like listing the things) and getting a different result.  I use this format because in my situation it is possible for my API calls to run in a slightly different order than it did last time.  If your tests are simpler, you might be able to get away with a simple list of request/response pairs.

I have a flag in my unit tests that indicate if I am in "record" mode (that is, talking to a real server and recording this data-structure to disk) or if I am in "playback" mode (talking to the datastructure).  When I need to work with a test, I "record" the interactions with the server and then play them back.

I use the little-known SenTestCaseDidStartNotification to track which unit test is running and isolate my data files appropriately.

The other thing to keep in mind is that instability is the root of all evil.  If you have code that does things with sets, or gets the current date, and such, this tends to change the requests and responses, which do not work in an offline scenario.  So be careful with those.

Answer (score 2):

(Since nobody stepped in yet and gave you a complete walkthrough) My humble advice: Step back a bit, take out the magic of async, regard everything as sync (api calls, parsing, persistence), and isolate each step as a consumer/producer. After all you don't wan't to unit-test NSURLConnection, or JSONKit or whatever (they should have been tested if you use them), you want to test YOUR code. Your code takes some input and produces output, non-aware of the fact that the input was in fact the output genereated in a background thread somewhere. You can do the isolated test all sync.

Can we agree on the fact that your Views don't care about how their model data was provided? If yes, well, test your View with mock objects.

Can we agree on the fact that your parser doesn't care about how the data was provided? If yes, well, test your parser with mock data.

Network layer: same applies as described above, in the end you'll get an NSDictionary of headers, and some NSData or NSString of content. I don't think you want to unit-test NSURLConnection or any 3'rd party networking api you trust (asihttp, afnetworking,...?), so in the end, what's to be tested?
You can mock up URLs, request headers and POST data for each use-case you have, and setup test cases for expected responses.

In the end, IMHO, it's all about "normalizing" out asyc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Nocilla](https://github.com/luisobo/Nocilla)

For more info, check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15673653/351195) to a similar question